# Does xbuild really not implement the Move task?

Tags: mono, xbuild

Am I missing something, or does xbuild really not implement the `<Move>` task? I'm trying to build a cross-platform C# project using MSBuild files for everything so there will be less difference between Windows and Linux in our project, and my MSBuild file looks a little like this:

```
<Copy SourceFiles="$(SrcDir)/$(FirstFile);$(SrcDir)/$(SecondFile)" DestinationFolder="$(DestDir)" />
<Move SourceFiles="$(DestDir)/$(SecondFile)" DestinationFile="$(DestDir)/$(NewFileNameForSecondFile)" />
```

But when I run xbuild, it complains:

```
Error initializing task Move: Not registered task Move.
```

What am I missing? I know that xbuild doesn't implement some of MSBuild's more recent and/or more advanced features — I've had to work around a few of those omissions — but the `<Move>` task seems like a really, really basic one. Is it really not implemented in xbuild, or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* **Move** falls under TaskExtensions within MSBuild. You would need to convert it to a **Copy** and **Delete** or multiple platform specific Tasks:

List of TaskNames in xbuild (mono 4.2.x):

```
cd mono/mcs/tools/xbuild
grep -RI "TaskName=" * | cut -d "=" -f 2 | cut -d "      " -f 1 | sort | uniq
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AL"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssignCulture"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssignLinkMetadata"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssignProjectConfiguration"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssignTargetPath"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CallTarget"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CombinePath"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CreateCSharpManifestResourceName"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CreateItem"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CreateProperty"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CreateVisualBasicManifestResourceName"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Csc"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Delete"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Error"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Exec"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.FindAppConfigFile"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.FindUnderPath"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GetAssemblyIdentity"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GetFrameworkPath"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GetFrameworkSdkPath"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GetReferenceAssemblyPaths"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.LC"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.MSBuild"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.MakeDir"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Message"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReadLinesFromFile"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.RemoveDir"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.RemoveDuplicates"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveAssemblyReference"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.SignFile"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Touch"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Vbc"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Warning"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.WriteCodeFragment"
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.WriteLinesToFile"
```

Comment: Looks like you're right about TaskExtensions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff595163.aspx says that the Move task "inherits parameters from the TaskExtension class...". I was able to get the same effects via Copy and Delete, just like you suggested, but it's good to know that I wasn't missing something obvious. Thanks for a good, detailed answer.